# Why are smartphone antennas not $\lambda/2$ of the wavelength? Why are patch-antennas used instead of simple dipole antennas?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, antennas, radio-frequency

Why are smartphone antennas not $\lambda/2$ of the wavelength? Why are patch-antennas used instead of simple dipole antennas?

I'm very new to this but really interested in using basic physics to explain everyday items. Thank you!

Comment: You're basically asking for a pretty comprehensive introduction to antenna design, which really requires a solid background in theory of electromagnetic waves; this is what you'd learn after 2 to 4 years of university (electrical engineering with a focus on RF/communications technology), not in an answer to a question on here. The only sensible answer I could think of on this level is "because you *can*; reasons: see the physics of electromagnetic waves, especially Maxwell". Otherwise, I'd have to reproduce multiple lextures on differential equations, Maxwell, transmission line theory,Fourier,

Comment: analysis of basic antennas and aperture antennas, each going for a full semester. This really might be more than you really wanted!

Comment: I am a physics student so the physics are no problem. With patch antennas, I think there must be practical or rather electrical-engenineering focused answers (maybe because they can detect a signal more easy with broader design or such). If you say that there is a more empirically-found not theory based answer I am satisfied with that :). I don't know but maybe in smartphones lambda/4 antennas are also enough - meaning the signal is strong enough?

Comment: Your suspicion about smartphones is definitely not accurate. We need any nanowatt we can.

Comment: If the physics are no problem, you should ask a more precise question describing what you've already figured out. And honestly, you might be a bit overvconfident in your abilities, no offense: this is a lot of math-y tricks and engineering methods that you might simply not have worked with. We (all EE students in Karlsruhe, home of Hertz ;D ) did the same math as the physics students during my EE studies, but I then learned all this stuff focused in a way that it makes sense for antenna design; that was more than the common math.

Comment: Well, but there is no way around lambda/2 antennas right? Still (at least not for 5G) they are smaller...

Comment: there's definitely ways around $\lambda/2$, as you can see from the fact that your phone's 800 MHz antenna isn't  9.375cm long.

Comment: I study math as well :). But at least you're agree that smartphone antennas are smaller than $\lambda/2$ right?

Comment: again, I don't doubt you've got the *abilities*, it's just *a large field over which you ask for an a pretty comprehensive introduction*. "I know physics and math, I can build a computer!" makes about as much sense – no, you can't.

Comment: So could you provide me any catchwords on which way there are ways around it? I'd love to dig into these things and maybe find a rather simple solution (e.g. complex software, etc.)

Comment: I told you the titles/central topics of the lectures you need to learn. Have fun! Start with understanding Maxwell under much less beautiful boundary conditions than what a physics undergrad (or a graduate student *not* doing their work on wave phenomena) does. Then, learn about transmission line theory; then about applications of the  Fourier transform in continuous distributed current aperture antennas (again, boundary conditions), then quite likely also about discrete Fourier transform for antenna arrays. Then you can tackle practical antenna design, which will also incorporate real-world

Comment: material sciences, understanding active microwave semiconductor elements, simulative methods... It might also help avoiding misunderstandings like "the signal is strong enough" if you understood a few basics of communications technology, i.e. theory of time-discrete and -continuous signals, the theory of signal estimation and transmission over stochastic channels, detection, error correction, methods of modulation, and a bit about spectrum regulation. Round that off with an understanding of the eigenvalue systems/optimization problems inherent to multi-antenna systems, and multi-user access.

Comment: If you do this at the same depth our departments offers, at this point you'd have done 66% of my B.Sc. + M.Sc. degrees :) Don't expect results tomorrow!

Comment: Wow, very impressive. I'll get back to you when I am done ;) Thank you.

Comment: why do you expect that *any* antenna should have $\lambda/2$ length?

Comment: For what it's worth I thought the wikipedia articles on [patch antennas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_antenna) and [Inverted-F antennas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted-F_antenna) gave a reasonably clear overview of the issues and history. I'm a physicist but not an expert in this area by any means so I can't really judge if the articles are complete or correct, but my impression was that they were a reasonable high-level overview, had references to more literature, and specifically addressed the size of the antennas.